# Deducing additional set theoretic properties from definition of dynkin system

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove certain set theoretic properties assuming dynkin system. 
Definition of Dynkin system - 
Let $X$ be a non empty set and let D be a collection of subsets of $X$, Then $D$ is a dynkin system if -

1. $X \in D$ .
2. If $A$ and $B$ belongs to $D$ and $A \subseteq B$, then $B \setminus A$ belongs to $D$.
3. If $A_1, A_2, \dots$ is a sequence of subsets such that $ A_n \subseteq A_{n+1} $ for all $n \ge 1$ , then $\bigcup\limits_{n =1}^{\infty}A_n \in D$.

In following properties to be proved properties I don't know how they are true or please give some Counterexample. I am only interested how to prove them if intersection of two arbitrary sets assumed is non empty as I have already proved for disjoint sets. 
Properties are -

1. Assume sets $A$ and $B$  belong to $D$ and they have non empty intersection, does $A \cap  B$ always belong to $D$.
2. Assume  sets $A$ and $B$ belong to $D$ and they have non empty intersection , does $A \cup B$ always belong to $D$ .

Comment: Hi, please read up about [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @SimoneRamello hope question is fine now. Can you please give some hints. I am really struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A,B\subset X$ such that the sets $A\cap B$, $A\cap B^{\complement}$, $A^{\complement}\cap B$ and $A^{\complement}\cap B^{\complement}$ are not empty.

Let $\mathcal D:=\{\varnothing, A,A^{\complement},B, B^{\complement},X\}$.

Then $\mathcal D$ is a Dynkin-system but this with $A\cap B\notin\mathcal D$ and $A\cup B\notin\mathcal D$.

---

Observe that for $D_1,D_2\in\mathcal D$ we have $D_1\subseteq D_2$ if and only if one of the following conditions is satisfied:

- $D_1=D_2$
- $D_1=\varnothing$
- $D_2=X$

This makes it easy to verify that $\mathcal D$ is indeed a Dynkin-system.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Both assumptions are incorrect.

As a counter example consider:

X={1,2,3,4}, D={{}, {1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{2,3},{2,4},{3,4},X}