# Deducing additional properties of semi algebra from defination of semi algebra

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove additional properties of semi algebra assuming defination of *semi algebra* .

Definition of semi algebra:

A class $\mathcal S\subseteq\wp(X)$ is called semi algebra over $X$  if:

- 1. Empty set and whole set are in $\mathcal S$.
- 2. It is closed under finite intersection, i.e. if $A, B$ are in $\mathcal S$ then  $A\cap B$ is also in $\mathcal S$.
- 3. Set difference of any two sets in $\mathcal S$ is finite disjoint union of elements in $\mathcal S$.

---

I am trying to prove (or disprove) the following properties. Can someone please help.

- 1. if $A$ belongs to $\mathcal S$, then so does the complement of $A$.
- 2. If $A$ and $B$ belong to $\mathcal S$, then so does $A\cup B$.
- 3. If $A$ and $B$ belong to $\mathcal S$, and $A$ is a subset of $B$, then so does $B\setminus A$.
- 4. If $A_1, A_2,\dots$ upto infinity belong to $\mathcal S$, then so does $ \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$.

Please give some hint.

Comment: Hi, please read up about [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @SimoneRamello  hope the question is fine now. can you please give some hint

Comment: I think in 4) "belongs to $B$" is meant to be "belongs to $S$".

Comment: @drhab yes really sorry

Comment: Please check my edit.

Comment: @drhab  thank you for editing.  I am sorry my mathjax is not good as I am just a beginer on this site

Comment: Answer in short: in general a semi algebra does not have any of the (additional) properties that you mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let it be that the sets $A,B,C$ form a partition of $X$ and let $\mathcal S:=\{\varnothing,A,B,C,X\}$.

It is not difficult to prove that $\mathcal S$ is a semi algebra.

Now try to find answers on 1),2) and 4) with $\mathcal S$ in mind.

---

Let $X=[0,10)$ and $\mathcal S':=\{[a,b)\mid 0\leq a\leq b\leq10\}$.

Then it can be shown that $\mathcal S'$ is a semi algebra.

Observe that $A,B\in\mathcal S'$ with $A\subseteq B$ if $A=[4,5)$ and $B=[3,6)$.

Now with this in mind try to find an answer on 3).

Comment: using example 1 of your answer 1 and 3 comes false. But 2 and 4 are true. So, if 2 and 4 are always true can you please give a rigorous proof. Also, using example 2 , 3 comes true  . So, why did you gave example 3

Comment: Can you please verify my claims

Comment: Using my first example $A,B\in\mathcal S$ but $A\cup B\notin\mathcal S$, so 2. is false (and also 4. is false). Further $A\cup B$ is the complement of $C$, so also 1. is false. My second example shows that 3. is false: $B-A=[3,4)\cup[5,6)\notin\mathcal S$.

Comment: thank you very much sir. If you have some time can you please give some hint for this question also asked by me in measure theory . https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3341694/deducing-additional-set-theoretic-properties-from-definition-of-dynkin-system